# How do I access key in object in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, jsx

I have an object which has key like **Assigned_To.Name:"Maxicus"** but when I try to access it in my JSX code then it treat my key like Assigned_To and then Name which means blank string. How can I access it combine ?

Comment: Please, provide some code.

Comment: `{your_obj["Assigned_To.Name"]}` ...

Comment: thanks @KcH it works. Please give  answer then I mark it accepted

Comment: is your `key` a `string`? like `"Assigned_To.Name" : "Maxicus"`. If it is not,I want to know how you used the  `.` in an object key